# Not getting correct result when entering triple integral from Basic Math Assistant palette

Tags: front-end, syntax

I entered the following expression into my Mathematica notebook using the Basic Math Assistant palette. It gives $ x ^ 7/30 $ instead of $1/198$ that I got by hand. Where is the error?

### $\qquad\int _0^1\int _0^x\int _0^{x y}x y^2 z^2dxdydz$

Comment: First read Documentation. Second use: `Integrate[x*y^2*z^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, x}, {z, 0, x*y}]`

Comment: HI , This happens to me when I use the "Basic Math Assistant"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the Basic Math Assistant palette to enter your integral it should look like this

[image: palette_input]

The differential-d terms must appear in the order inner-most to outer-most. You have them backwards.